# Azure Storage Multiple Image Upload

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, image-uploading, azure-mobile-services

How can I upload multiple images to Azure Storage from Windows Phone 8? I found a solution to upload single image, but I need to upload 3 images.

The solution that I found is below:

http://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-phone-upload-data-blob-storage/

I have an User Model, which have following properties.

```
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "gender")]
    public char Gender { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "birthdate")]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "location")]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "photo")]
    public System.Windows.Controls.Image Photo { get; set; }


    // For Blob Storage Photo Upload
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "containerName")]
    public string ContainerName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "resourceName")]
    public string ResourceName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "sasQueryString")]
    public string SasQueryString { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "imageUri")]
    public string ImageUri { get; set; } 

}
```

And, for register our application, user can upload a profile picture. The code for uploading a profile picture as follows:

```
    public RegisterVersion2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetBinding();
        BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        cameraCaptureTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
        cameraCaptureTask.ShowCamera = true;
        cameraCaptureTask.Completed += cameraCaptureTask_Completed;
    }

    void cameraCaptureTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        imageStream = e.ChosenPhoto;
        bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        profilPicture.Source = bmp;
    }

    private void photoChoose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cameraCaptureTask.Show();

    }
    async void Register(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Some code for getting input from user for username, email, password etc.I don't put this code here. 

        Model.User newUser = new Model.User
        { Email = email, UserName = username, Password = password, 
        BirthDate = birthday, Name = name + " " + surname, Gender = gender, 
        Phone = phone, ContainerName = username, ResourceName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg" };
        string errorString = string.Empty;
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

        if (imageStream != null)
        {
             await User.InsertAsync(newUser);
        }
        // Send the item to be inserted. When blob properties are set this
        // generates an SAS in the response.


        // If we have a returned SAS, then upload the blob.
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newUser.SasQueryString))
        {
        // Get the URI generated that contains the SAS 
        // and extract the storage credentials.
              StorageCredentials cred = new StorageCredentials(newUser.SasQueryString);
              var imageUri = new Uri(newUser.ImageUri);
              // Instantiate a Blob store container based on the info in the returned item.
              CloudBlobContainer container = new CloudBlobContainer(
              new Uri(string.Format("https://{0}/{1}",imageUri.Host, newUser.ContainerName)), cred);
              // Upload the new image as a BLOB from the stream.
              CloudBlockBlob blobFromSASCredential = container.GetBlockBlobReference(newUser.ResourceName);
              await blobFromSASCredential.UploadFromStreamAsync(imageStream);

              // When you request an SAS at the container-level instead of the blob-level,
              // you are able to upload multiple streams using the same container credentials.
              imageStream = null;

    }
```

My question is about uploading multiple images. For this time, I have an Item object, which again same properties as Id, ItemName, ItemCost, ItemDescription etc. However, for this time we need to have 3 different image upload. The properties below are used for one photo, also the code for uploading image is used for one photo. How can change it?

// For Blob Storage Photo Upload
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "containerName")]
        public string ContainerName { get; set; }

```
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "resourceName")]
    public string ResourceName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "sasQueryString")]
    public string SasQueryString { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "imageUri")]
    public string ImageUri { get; set; }
```

Comment: You're gonna need to provide a whole lot more context about the problem that you're trying to solve, along with the code that you are using right now.  The sample that you link to shows how to upload a single image - just call that for each image?

Comment: I added the code. As you can see it is not possible to call that for each image. Can you make any suggestion?